# Using persp in base R, my plot is all black when I want it to be red

Tags: r

I am a beginning R student and would appreciate any help that anyone here could offer!

I have plotted a bivariate distribution function using the following code:

```
shape <- function(x,y){
  (6/5)*(x+y^2)
}

x <- y <- seq(0, 1, length = 500)
z <- outer(x, y, shape)

persp(x, y, z, theta = 30, phi = 15, col = "red", shade = 0.5)
```

Since I included the bit about col = "red" and shade = 0.5, I thought my shape would appear red and beautifully shaded in "an approximation to daylight illumination" as promised in the help section.

However, my shape is uniformly black with no shading at all. Could anyone tell me what I am missing?

[image: My sad black shape]

Comment: you can change `border = NA` or another color but 500x500 seems excessive and takes several second to render

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what the problem was. I changed the length from 500 to just 15 and now it's red just as I was hoping for!